# Angular Material Select looses values when selecting one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am building a selection with the angular material select method. Everything looks fine however, when I am selecting a value from the `ng-options`, I am loosing all of the other values above. That means, in the next turn of selecting a value, I cannot see or choose them anymore. Does anyone know this problem?

**Html code:**

```
<md-input-container>
      <label>Zoom Options</label>
      <md-select ng-change="triggerZoom(zoomLevel)" ng-model="zoomLevel">
        <md-option ng-value="level.value" ng-repeat="level in zoomLevels">
          {{level.id}}
        </md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
```

**JS Code:**

```
$scope.zoomLevels = [
    {id: 'day', value: 1},
    {id: 'week', value: 7},
    {id: 'month', value: 30},
    {id: 'quarter', value: 90}
  ];

 $scope.zoomLevel = 1;

  $scope.triggerZoom = function(days) {
    console.log(days);
  };
```

Comment: Add a codepen or something?